# Android adding new locales behind a feature flag

Tags: android, localization, locale

What is the best way to add a new language (or locale) in android behind a feature flag so that I can enable it internally (we do have an option of different build variant for internal builds) for testing for a few weeks?

Or specifically if I can intercept locale resolution and add a feature flag such as if french is the new language added recently, I only want to show it in our internal build and for external builds users will continue seeing english.

Comment: Your best bet is probably a beta program rather than a feature flag.  There's really no way to prevent using translated strings when using the built in android string resource system

Comment: do you mean using resconfigs with different build variants?